# C# AJAX reloading the form

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm learning C# MVC and now creating a project.
I have a problem with understanding AJAX - I can't understand why it doesn't work. After clicking the save button the form is reloading (?). After the second click, the code goes to SearchRouts(). But then - just nothing happens. Neither code from success, nor from error block (I set simple alerts to check it). It looks like the form just reloads (?). I can't figure out what's happening.
I think it is something with the end of SearchRoutes() - should I send the response in another way?
Thank you for your help.

Here is my code:

#### Index.cs.html:

```
<form id="search_form" method="post">
    <label class="search__header">Długość: </label></br>
    <div class="search__options">
        <select class="search__select" name="search_len" id="search_len" multiple>
            <option value="len1">0-100 km</option>
            <option value="len2">100-150 km</option>
            <option value="len3">150-300 km</option>
            <option value="len4">+300 km</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label class="search__header">Difficulty: </label></br>
    <div class="search__options">
        <select class="search__select" name="search_dif" id="search_dif" multiple>
            <option value="easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="hard">Hard</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label class="search__header">Pavement: </label></br>
    <div class="search__options">
        <select class="search__select" name="search_pav" id="search_pav" multiple>
            <option value="asphalt">Asphalt</option>
            <option value="forest">Forest</option>
            <option value="mix">Mix</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="search_options search__options--submit">
        <img class="search__img" src="img/compass.png">
        <button class="panel__button panel__button--submit" id="search_submit" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### search.js:

```
    $("#search_submit").on("click", function () {
        console.log("SUBMIT CLICKED!");
        var search_obj = {}
        search_obj.Length = $("#search_len").val()[0];
        search_obj.Difficulty = $('#search_dif').val()[0];
        search_obj.Pavement = $('#search_pav').val()[0];
        console.log(search_obj);
        alert("ALERT!");
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/User/SearchRoutes',
            data: JSON.stringify(search_obj),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success!");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error. Try again.");
            }
        });
    
    });
```

#### UserController.cs:

```
    public ActionResult SearchRoutes([FromBody] JsonSearch search)
            {
                double min = 0;
                double max = 1000;
                if(search.Length=="len1")
                {
                    max = 100;
                }
                else if(search.Length=="len2") {
                    min = 100;
                    max = 150;
                }
                else if(search.Length=="len3")
                {
                    min = 150;
                    max = 300;
                }
                else
                {
                    min = 300;
                }
                var list = _userService.FindRoutes(min, max, search.Difficulty, search.Pavement);  // returns C# list of routes objects from database
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
                return Json(json);
            }
```

Comment: Your submit button is posting the form. You can return `false` from your javascript function to prevent it.

Comment: You mean returning false at the end of success and error blocks of code?

Comment: Return `false` from any execution path that exists to stop the form submission. This stops all event propagation, Another user has suggested `preventDefault` but that does not prevent event propagation all the way up the document. You have to decide which way you want it, but most likely return false.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript function call use

```
$("#search_submit").on("click", function (e) { 
    console.log("SUBMIT CLICKED!");
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

To skip the reload event after submit is pressed.